# How Can I Get Rid of An Image Link From WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, https

I am trying to **delete an image** from WordPress as it is affecting my **SSL**, except when I have deleted it on WordPress, **a link to the image still persists**.

The problem is if you enter **inspect mode on chrome** and look at the **console**, you see a **mixed content error** that states there is an **insecure image at `/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/Building-Website-Banner.png`** , to resolve this error **I deleted the image off the media section in WordPress**, except the link **still persists and continues the bug the SSL.**

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work: all I needed to do was **take another image** and **rename it to the same image as my buggy image** and **save it**. I don't know how or why it worked, but it did.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to find a solution and post it here.

Comment: You may have however a deeper issue as from my understanding the fact of solving it like that is strange: you have a "mixed content error", which means (you didn't give a lot of details) that you are accessing some HTTPS content and it has an image/script/css/font/etc. reference to an HTTP link which is nowadays source for errors on browsers (or just stopped loading). Removing the image wouldn't change the HTTP link and hence the error. Overwriting the image with another file wouldn't change the HTTP link either. So maybe something specific to WordPress but still strange. PS: do not abuse bold